# Definition of operation and method in OOP

Tags: oop, object, methods, operation

I'm searching for a concrete definition of **operation** and **method** independent of the programming language.

In my understanding:

> Operations just specify which functionality an object supports without
>   any implementation. It seems to be like a prototype in a C header.
>
> Methods specify the concrete implementations an object supports. It seems to be like an implemented C function.

**Question:**

Why do we speak of *abstract* methods? In my opinion abstract methods should be the same like operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching [pascal.computer.org](https://pascal.computer.org/) for **operation** gives numerous and varied definitions. In the context of this question, the second seems most fitting.

> in programming, a defined action that can be performed by a computer system

That definition sounds vague in isolation, but ties nicely into the definition of **method**.

> implementation of an operation

...which is exactly as stated in the question. However, I think these formal definitions differ from colloquial usage. The term *operation* is somewhat rare in OOP. I would use it in the context of a mathematical operation, especially as the action of a mathematical *operator*, but not as a substitute for a method definition. *Abstract method* would be a more common phrase in that case.

Likewise, while *method* is a quintessential OOP term, it is not typically used to call out an implementation. *Concrete method* would be the inverse of abstract method. I think the lesson is that while academic definitions exist, programmers don't necessarily speak that way. This is no different to common conversation diverging from the dictionary.

See also: [What's the difference between a method and a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)